# Understanding JVM guarantees for immutable objects

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

*Java Concurrency in Practice* has the following example:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
    private volatile OneValueCache cache = new OneValueCache(null, null);

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);
        if (factors == null) {
            factors = factor(i);
            cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
        }
            encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
        }
    }
}
```

The `OneValueCache` is immutable.

From what I understand using `volatile` ensures that all threads see up-to-date reference stored in the `cache` variable.

At the same time it says that

> Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional
>       synchronization, even when synchronization is not used to publish them.

For me it says that we actually don't need that `volatile` above that we used for synchronization.

`JLS` also has the following example:

```
class FinalFieldExample {
    final int x;
    int y; 

    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3;
        y = 4;
    }

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    }

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x; // guaranteed to see 3
            int j = f.y; // could see 0
        }
    }
}
```

They don't use `volatile` for field `f`. Doesn't it mean that other threads can see `f` as `null` and never see the created instance?

Could someone explain?

Comment: The object is immutable, the variable is not.

Comment: You're conflating two very different things:

 - An object, if designated as immutable, is threadsafe.

 - A variable (that refers to an object) is open to pointing to any other object, hence the need for the `volatile` keyword to ensure that whatever component is using the variable has access to the latest copy of whatever the variable refers to

Comment: What confused me was `Immutable objects can be published through any mechanism.` Assigning to a variable is a mechanism, but it wouldn't be thread-safe to do it, right?

Comment: Because we use volatile we could also use a effectively mutable class in the first example. Volatile guarantees that construction will not be reordered with assignment to a volatile. And reading thread would see it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand using `volatile` ensures that all threads see up-to-date reference stored in the cache variable.

That's right, but this concept applies to the variable while the statement quoted from JCiP

> Immutable objects can be used safely by any thread without additional
>   synchronization, even when synchronization is not used to publish them.

does not apply to a variable but to the object itself. It means that a thread will always see a fully constructed object without any data races independent on how it is published because as JCiP states

> Immutable objects can be published through any mechanism.

Now in regard to your second example:

> Doesn't it mean that other threads can see f as null and never see the created instance?

That is right. If one thread calls `writer()` other thready may see `f` as `null` or `f.y` as `0` because it does not respect safe publication:

> 3.5.3. Safe Publication Idioms
>
> To publish an object safely, both the reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to other threads at the same time.
>   A properly constructed object can be safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from a static initializer;
> - Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or AtomicReference;
> - Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed > object; or
> - Storing a reference to it into a field that is properly guarded by a lock.

Comment: `can be published through any mechanism`. Isn't assigning to a `cache` variable a publishing mechanism?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you refer to my statement that it `does not apply to a variable but to the object itself`? This was in regard to `Immutable objects can be used safely`.